# Как вывести время, которое само изменяется?

Tags: php, javascript

Как на js вывести время которое само изменяется? Что бы не надо было перезагружать страницу, а оно само изменялось.

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал и про сетинтервал и с примером разобрался !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завалялся готовый скрипт.

```
setInterval(function(){
    date = new Date();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = date.getDate() + '.' + date.getMonth() + '.' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
}, 1000);
```